# vectorizing numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy array like the one below:

```
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [6, 6]])
```

I am interesting in doing a dot product operation between each row by itself. For example, suppose I want to dot the first row with itself:

```
ans = x[0,:] @ x[0,:].T

ans = 13
```

And the second:

```
ans = x[1,:] @ x[1,:].T

ans = 52
```

```
ans = x[2,:] @ x[2,:].T
and = 72
```

Is there a way to vectorize this operation without using `numpy.apply_along_axis`? Desired output would be

```
array([13, 52, 72])
```

It doesn't have to be this specific operation. To be specific I am performing an SVM implementation and I have a few kernels that I want to vectorize over my m x d feature matrix. How can I do this?

Comment: `(x*x).sum(axis=1)` is one way

Comment: `x[0.:].T` the transpose doesn't change anything.  Try it!

Answer (score 0):

```py
np.square(x[:,0]) + np.square(x[:,1])
```

output

```
array([13, 52, 72], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
numpy.linalg.norm(a,axis=1)**2
```

giving you the norm of each row ans squaring it.